# Unramified extension over $ \mathbb{Q}_{p} $

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-numbers, p-adic

Let $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ be a p-adic field such that $ p \neq 2 $. We knew that for every $ n=2m $ there exists exactly one unramified extension $ K $ of $ \mathbb{Q}_{p} $ of degree $ n $, obtained by adjoining $ (p^n -1)$-th roots of unity to $ \mathbb{Q}_{p}$
. Moreover $ Gal(K / \mathbb{Q}_p) $ is isomorphic to $Gal(F_{p^n} : F_p) $ which is cyclic and generated by the Frobenius map.
Then what will be the generator of $ Gal(K / \mathbb{Q}_p) $???
Moreover if $ p\equiv 3 (mod 4 ) $ then does primitive $ 8^th $ root of unity belonging to the the quadratic extension in the extension  $(K / \mathbb{Q}_p) $?

Comment: The isomorphism between Galois groups of the field extension and the residue field extension is canonical, so there’s a canonical generator corresponding to frobenius

Comment: From Hensel’s lemma there’s a primitive 8th root of unity in $K$ if there’s one in the residue field of $K$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify $f$: it should be equal to $n$. A particular generator of the resulting cyclic Galois group is the Frobenius automorphism, which acts on the $(p^n−1)$-th roots of unity by $x\mapsto x^p$. The quadratic subextension is generated by the $(p^2-1)$-th roots of unity. As $p^2-1$ is divisible by $8$, this subextension contains a primitive $8$-th root of unity.

Comment: Yes f=n. What will be image of primitive 8th root

Comment: @Sky Image under what?

Comment: Image under the generator of the cyclic group

Comment: @Sky Well, there are several generators of a cyclic group. The Frobenius automorphism is a particular generator, and it maps each $8$-th root of unity to its $p$-th power. As I said in my post.

Comment: I understand that any power of primitive $ p^{n} -1$-th  primitive root of unity is going to $ p$-th power of that. But can we say anything for an arbitrary element $ x\in K$? Although we know this is simple extension it is sufficicient to know  the image of primitive $ p^{n} -1$-th root of unity. But Can we say something about the image of an arbitrary element $ x \in K$.. Everytime it would not be go to $ x^p$ , for an example if we take a non trivial element in ground field

Comment: @Sky  how would you describe the action of the Galois group over $\mathbf Q$ of a cyclotomic field $\mathbf Q(\zeta_m)$ on arbitrary $x$ in $\mathbf Q(\zeta_m)$? On $m$th roots of unity, the Galois group acs by raising them to powers relatively prime to $m$. But how do you describe the Galois action on a general $x$? (It is *not* raising $x$ to some power bigger than $1$, since power maps are not additive in characteristic $0$.) If you can answer this question then you have a chance of answering your $p$-adic question. If you can't answer this question then think about it until you can.

Comment: @Sky The elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are fixed, while the $(p^n-1)$-th roots of unity get raised to $p$-th power. These two things determine the whole action on $K$, because $K$ is generated by the $(p^n-1)$-th roots of unity over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. The key term is "generated". Think about what that means, that is, how can one express an element of $K$ in terms of $(p^n-1)$-th roots of unity and the elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. See also KConrad's comment above.

Comment: Can you give some reference @MO where we can knew that that primitive p^n -1 root of unity is going to p^th power of that

Comment: @Sky See Corollary 2 on Page 18 of Weil: Basic number theory. In fact I recommend Chapter I as a whole: it presents the structure theory of local fields in 23 pages, in a precise, concise and self-contained way (modulo the structure theory of finite fields which is used as a prerequisite).